# What is the correct way to create and configure a litle Spring project that will be add to some Spring MVC projects to retrieve common info?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-data

I have the following situation.

I have some Spring MVC application that share a database that contain the users informations and the authorities of these users.

So I have to do the following operation: I have to create a Spring "module" (I relly don't know if module is the appropriate term) that simply implement the service and the repository that retrieve these informations. Then I have to add this "module" to all the Spring MVC projects (so I can write the component that retrieve the user information one time and simply add it to the current web project as a dependency).

For this module I have to configure the JPA connection to the database and the beans definition.

My doubt is: have I to create a **beans.xml** file related to this module (the project added as dependency of the Spring MVC project) or can I configure these bean and this connection into the **root-context.xml** file (the file that conigure the bean of the Spring MVC project to which this module is added) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually done something similar recently. My approach (we used Hibernate) was to have all of the mapping files, database connection setup, DAO layer beans and Service layer beans be included in the jar that was the dependency of the web app. It cuts down on the duplication of basic bean setup (we still use XML config instead of annotations).

Answer (score 0):

When a Spring MVC application starts it takes the configuration from the file you configured before. Based on your description you're using somehting like this

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

If you have some configuration in other Spring xml file, you need to imported to the root file.

```
<import resource="connection/Spring-Connection.xml"/>
```

Here there are three links that will help you

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/load-multiple-spring-bean-configuration-file/

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/

Answer (score 0):

start with `start.spring.io`. There you can choose the modules you want to include in your application and can get started from there.